# How to write into a file at particular path in linux using C

Tags: c, linux

I want to write in file `chunkcombined.playlist` located at the path `/var/streaming/playlists/chunkcombined/chunkcombined.playlist` using C.

As the files (small chunks of video) get received through a socket, I want to add them automatically to a playlist.

For that I want to write the following lines in the file `chunkcombined.playlist` using C:

```
"/usr/local/movies//chunk0.mp4" 1
"/usr/local/movies//chunk1.mp4" 1
"/usr/local/movies//chunk2.mp4" 1
"/usr/local/movies//chunk3.mp4" 5
"/usr/local/movies//chunk4.mp4" 5
```

How can I write into a file at particular path in Linux using C?

Comment: Why not to use bash script since you are on linux.

Comment: Please note that a regular user typically can't write freely under /usr/local, there will be permission-based restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`fopen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/) and [`fputs()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fputs/) functions.

Full example (with excessive comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* where to write */
    const char filepath[] =
        "/var/streaming/playlists/chunkcombined/chunkcombined.playlist";

    /* what to write */
    const char output_lines[] = 
        "\"/usr/local/movies//chunk0.mp4\" 1\n"
        "\"/usr/local/movies//chunk1.mp4\" 1\n"
        "\"/usr/local/movies//chunk2.mp4\" 1\n"
        "\"/usr/local/movies//chunk3.mp4\" 5\n"
        "\"/usr/local/movies//chunk4.mp4\" 5\n";

    /* define file handle */ 
    FILE *output;

    /* open the file */
    output = fopen(filepath, "wb");
    if(output == NULL) return -1; /* fopen failed */

    /* write the lines */
    fputs(output_lines, output);

    /* close the file */
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

This version retrieves the text line given as argument to the program and then writes it to desired file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argv[1] == NULL) return -1; /* no arguments, bail out */

    /* where to write */
    const char filepath[] =
        "/var/streaming/playlists/chunkcombined/chunkcombined.playlist";

    /* define file handle */ 
    FILE *output;

    /* open the file */
    output = fopen(filepath, "wb"); /* change "wb" to "ab" for append mode */
    if(output == NULL) return -1; /* fopen failed */

    /* write the lines */
    fputs(argv[1], output);
    putc('\n', output);

    /* close the file */
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

`./write "\"Hello, World!\""`

writes: `"Hello, World!"`

to:

`/var/streaming/playlists/chunkcombined/chunkcombined.playlist`.

Comment: No problem. It would be polite to tag this answer as "accepted" if it was helpful.